# Why does DirectUploadsController#create take checksum as a parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

I'm building an active storage direct upload component with a custom (react) frontend so I'm not using the out-of-the-box Rails frontend helpers.

When I post my file data to the backend to get the presigned url, I get this issue:

```
ArgumentError (missing keyword: :checksum):
```

[Here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/358d3d3164bef399b19b089f5fed8664a2c3d39e/activestorage/app/controllers/active_storage/direct_uploads_controller.rb) you can see that the controller needs a checksum parameter from the frontend.

How does this make sense? For the checksum to be calculated on the frontend, the AWS secret key needs to be on the client which is a huge security flaw. Is this assumption incorrect? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: The checksum is just a simple MD5 checksum. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/358d3d3164bef399b19b089f5fed8664a2c3d39e/activestorage/app/assets/javascripts/activestorage.esm.js#L417

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/358d3d3164bef399b19b089f5fed8664a2c3d39e/activestorage/app/assets/javascripts/activestorage.js#L610C7-L610C19

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Rails, but requiring the checksum in advance for S3 uploads is [a pretty common pattern](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/checking-object-integrity.html).

The flow is as follows:

- The frontend calculates the checksum of the file it's going to upload and sends it to the backend.
- The backend generates a pre-signed upload URL which has the checksum and an instruction for S3 to check it baked into it.
- The frontend uploads the file directly to S3, using the pre-signed URL.
- S3 calculates the checksum of the uploaded file. If it doesn't match the checksum in the URL, it rejects the upload.

If the upload URL leaks, the attacker won't be able to use it to upload anything but a file with the same checksum.

The frontend does need to know the file contents before uploading to calculate the checksum, but it doesn't need to have an AWS secret to do that.